# Python PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to save txt to program files(x86)

Tags: python, windows, text, save

I know there are other questions like this but none of them have helped. Here is the full code:

```
    save_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mod Tool\Infractions\Kicks'
    name_of_file = whoisit
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file + ".txt")
    file1 = open(completeName, "w")
    file1.write("Username: " + whoisit + "  //  "+ whatisit + " // Reason: " + reason)
    file1.close()
    print("Infraction stored.")
    print("")
    print("/kick" + ":" + whoisit + ":" + reason)
    print("")
    start()
```

To take you through, save_path is the folder I want it to save in (the txt will be saved in the Kicks folder)

Comment: Are you sure that the file you are trying to write to is not opened in any other application?

Comment: There's 2 possibilities I can think of.  1. `To write to that folder you need admin permissions` 2. `The file is opened by another program still.`

Comment: Requiring "run as administrator" to get elevated access was meant to encourage developers to write code that works for standard users. A better design would save per-user data under `%LocalAppData%` or `%AppData%` (roaming), or for all users under `%ProgramData%`. The latter requires modifying security on a subdirectory (e.g. via icacls.exe) to allow all users to modify files. That could also be done for a sudirectory of the application directory under `%ProgramFiles%`, but `%ProgramData%`is the more obvious place for program data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to run as admin in windows in order to write to program files.
Try to run as administrator.

usually: right click -> run as administrator.